# Сохранение большого количества переменных в файл

Tags: c#

У меня есть такие значения:

```
x = 3452.7807
y.= 67.07
Z = 13.568
```

Нужно их как-то сохранить, а затем прочитать. Нужно, чтобы получилось что-то типа такого:

```
Checkpoint_1:

x = 3452.7807
y.= 67.07
Z = 13.568

Checkpoint_2:

x = 345552.7807
y.= 67.0567
Z = 13.568
```

И так далее...

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вы что то пытались уже написать? Алгоритм такой: 1) открыть файл 2) Записать в файл 3) Закрыть файл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует много различных вариантов сохранения данных, в данном случае можно использовать сериализацию.

Сериализация представляет процесс преобразования какого-либо объекта в поток байтов. После преобразования этот поток байтов можно записать на диск или сохранить его временно в памяти. Так же можно выполнить обратный процесс - десериализацию - получить из потока байтов ранее сохраненный объект.

В C#, по умолчанию, есть 4 класса-сериализатора, которые работают со следующими форматами:

- бинарный ([`BinaryFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx));
- SOAP ([`SoapFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter(v=vs.110).aspx));
- XML ([`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx));
- JSON ([`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Продемонстрирую на примере формата JSON. Для начала нужно пометить атрибутами те данные, которые мы хотим сохранить. Класс помечается атрибутом `DataContract`, а  его свойства - атрибутом `DataMember`:

```
[DataContract]
public class CheckPoint
{
    public CheckPoint (double x = 0, double y = 0, double z = 0)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public double X { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double Y { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

Представим, что в списке `List<CheckPoint> checkPoints` у нас есть 10 объектов, чтобы их записать в файл необходимо воспользоваться методом `WriteObject()` класса `DataContractJsonSerializer`:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonFormatter = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<CheckPoint>));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("checkPoints.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    jsonFormatter.WriteObject(fs, checkPoints);
}
```

Для чтения используется метод `ReadObject()`:

```
List<CheckPoint> newCheckPoints;
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonFormatter = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<CheckPoint>));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("checkPoints.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    newCheckPoints = (List<CheckPoint>)jsonFormatter.ReadObject(fs);
}
```

Файл будет выглядеть следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]